# Creating Dummy Variable

Tags: r

This is how my data looks like:

```
         Attribute        Time     V1 V2 V3 V4
1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12 51 34 17
2 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 84 28 17 10
3 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 11 43 28 15
4 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 80 26 17 91
5 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-26 10 41 25 13
6 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25 97 35 23 12
```

I would like to create a dummy column "t" which creates same value when the dates are similar for eg, 1 for 2013-04-30 , 2 for 26-04-2013 and 3 for 25-04-2013. Its huge data so it would be helpful if there is less handwork. The data I require is given below:

```
         Attribute        Time     t V1 V2 V3 V4
1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 1 12 51 34 17
2 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 1 84 28 17 10
3 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 1 11 43 28 15
4 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 1 80 26 17 91
5 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-26 2 10 41 25 13
6 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25 3 97 35 23 12
```

Comment: Why do you need that variable? Using `as.factor` on Time column will give you numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data.frame is called `dfr`, try:

```
dfr$t <- as.numeric(as.factor(dfr$Time))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you are looking for just `as.factor` or if you need some kind of cumulative count of consecutive dates, in which case you could do this...

```
df$t <- cumsum( c( 1 , ! head(df$Time,-1) == tail(df$Time,-1) ) )

#              Attribute       Time V1 V2 V3 V4 t
#1 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 12 51 34 17 1
#2 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 84 28 17 10 1
#3 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 11 43 28 15 1
#4 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-30 80 26 17 91 1
#5 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-26 10 41 25 13 2
#6 pmEulRlcUserPacketThp 2013-04-25 97 35 23 12 3
```

We compare consecutive values of the `Time` column against one another to see if they are the same. Using the `!` operator we get FALSE if they are the same and TRUE if they are different. We can then `cumsum` this to get out result (with an initial `1` to start the ball rolling).